# Scraping ASPX after login with Python but every login gives you a different URL

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get the exam result data from my college website for every Roll No. in my class.

Normally you can POST url ([www.example.com/login.aspx](http://www.example.com/login.aspx))with login information, and GET a fixed url after login([www.example.com/home.aspx](http://www.example.com/home.aspx)).

But the page I'm trying to get has a different URL for every Roll no. entered. The URL of login page look like this: "www.example.com/View.aspx". After login, the URL of the result page looks like: "www.example.com/ovengine.aspx?enc=BunchOfNumbersandAlphabets". And those numbers and alphabets are different for each roll number.

So I can't put a URL in my code to get the final result. I don't know how to get the page that comes automatically after the login, without mentioning it's URL.

Comment: Hi @Jayant, nice to meet you, do you have any code or have you tried something so far?)

Answer (score 0):

> But the page I'm trying to get has a different URL for every Roll no. entered

No, it is the same URL, and the URL has a parameter. You see this in URL's all the time.

So,  for a temperature site it might look like

[www.TheWeatherSite.com/?City=Rome](http://www.TheWeatherSite.com/?City=Rome)

So, the above URL is always the same, but the web site "city" parameter is for the City of Rome. The web code behind can thus use/get/grab/consume that parameter in the code behind. That way we don't create a web page for EACH weather for each city.

so you create ONE page, and then and then PASS the web page a city value that the code behind can consume and use. (say query temperature data from a database for city = above value).

And thus you have to know ahead of time what city you want the weather for. Of course this approach is great since you don't have to create a new web site page to just show/display the weather in a given city.

You are in effect passing a value to some code behind that will run, and use that passed value.

The same goes for your example URL. You note there is ONE parameter called "enc".

So, the web site code behind would:

Grab, get, set the users ID. However, the users ID would be from the security system and the authentication provider. Unless you logged in as that particular user, then you not get that user id.

So, both a user ID (limited to the internal code).
And the "enc" value as the parameter in the URL you have would be required.

So, note in the above sql, we VERY likely need both a studentID and ALSO the "enc" value that some OTHER code from another page gets/grabs from the database.

Now that funny "GUID" (please do google what a GUID is), from a programmers point of view WOULD be sufficient to pull this one row of data from the database, but by ALSO using in the query the users logged on internal id?

Well, then only a given logged on user would be able to see their own set of values that belong to them.

In other words?

Only a drunken un-employed Rodeo clown would JUST require that GUID for pulling out that data. Since if that was the case, then any user could type in that GUID and see others peoples marks. However, there is "some" security by using a GUID, since a user could never guess that value.

If they used "city" like my first URL and parameter example? Then yes, you could guess and know the city value to type in. Or they could have used say student name, or even student number - those you COULD guess with relative ease.

But, for such data, no doubt the user adopted something MUCH more difficult then a starting number like a row number or PK id from a database. So, when the code added the results to that table? They also added a GUID of some type and saved that as a row in the database also.

So you NOT only need JUST the GUID, but that URL will ONLY work for a given pair of values. (the student ID - which is ONLY internal to the code and pulled FROM the authenticated provider. That was this line of code:

```
= Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey
```

So that above value is going to be the users logon internal ID.

The enc (external) exposed value in the web URL as a parameter, and ALSO the internal logged on value. So the code behind (asp.net) would look something like this:

```
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT * from tblStudentMarks where StudentID = @pID " &
             " AND TestResultsGID = @GID"

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, GetCon)

    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@pID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@GID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Request.QueryString("enc")
    Dim dReader As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)

    Dim rstData As DataTable
    dReader.Fill(rstData)
```

Note the code:

```
Request.QueryString("enc")
```

That allows the code behind to get/grab the parameter (enc) from the URL. But, as I stated, it is high unlikely that JUST the "enc" number is required here. It is possible that ONLY this value is required to pull the data from the row, but then that would be a security hole the size of a open barn door.

Think of your on-line banking.

[www.mybank.com/?CustomerNumber=1234](http://www.mybank.com/?CustomerNumber=1234)

Well, if we JUST use the above CustomerNumber as the means to pull bank data, then I could go to the site and type in YOUR number, or someone's else's number.

So, for this to work?
You will need to obtain a list of enc values (that messy funny long string). Without that parameter then you not be able to set the parameter in the URL.

However, as I stated, you ALSO very likely need some internal "user" logon id that is NOT included in the public exposed URL to ALSO grab that one row of data from the database.

And, even more important? Such web pages usually cannot be hit UNLESS you are a logged in as an authenticated user. In other words that web page will ONLY be dished out to logged in users - if you not logged in, then the server security will automatic NOT dish out the web page unless you are logged in user.

So, for this to work, you need to contact the web site developers, and obtain that list of "enc" values. Once you have that list, then you can generate some code to process that list and insert the correct parameter in the URL. However, you also need to ask if that URL and parameter value will work for JUST you the logged in user, or if that this URL and parameter ONLY works for a give logged in user. Without these values, and without knowing if the URL and parameter will work for any user? (which I doubt it would), then just using a URL to get these values will not work.

It would be even BETTER to have the web site folks create a web service that you can call and in one command it would return all of the data you need anyway, as opposed to over and over having to send the "enc" value, which you don't have anyway.